# Explode CSS Grid grandchild out of the width of its parent in Tailwind CSS?

Tags: html, css, next.js, css-grid, tailwind-css

I want to have a CSS Grid grandchild out of the width of its parent.

My reproducible demo -> https://play.tailwindcss.com/jZdsHpPAad

I have the following CSS Grid Wrapper:

```html
<div class="wrapper grid grid-cols-[1fr,70px,min(70ch,calc(100%-64px)),70px,1fr] gap-8 mb-24">
  <div class="mt-24 col-[3/4]">
    <dl>
      <dt class="sr-only">Published on</dt>
      <dd class="mb-2 font-medium text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
        <time datetime="2021-07-14T11:46:03.123Z">July 14, 2021</time>
      </dd>
    </dl>
    <ShiftBy x="{-2}">
      <h1 class="text-5xl font-alegreya">20 More Mindfuck Movies For The Brain Scrambling Experience</h1>
    </ShiftBy>
  </div>
  <div class="prose dark:prose-light col-[3/4]">
    <p class="sw-para">The predecessor to this list of mindfuck feature films showcased the average mind-numbing and quasi-discomposing stories from some great film makers. While you relished <a href="http://www.scoopwhoop.com/entertainment/20-mindfuck-hollywood-movies/" target="_blank">the previous list</a>, we felt we should explore different aspects and shades of an epic mindfuck. From the uneasy viewing to the unsettling, the 'what did I just watch' to the 'why did I just watch this', here's a renewed thought-blender list we compiled for you.</p>

    <h2>1. Neco Z Alenky/Alice (1988)&nbsp;</h2>
    <p class="sw-para">A surreal and almost grimy adaptation of <i>Alice In Wonderland, </i>Czech&nbsp;director Jan Svankmajer managed to come up with a low budget film with a unique perspective on retelling the story and far from elaborate filming devices like stop motion and dark lighting. <i>Alice</i>&nbsp;is a complete trip.</p>
    <figure class="sw-media col-[2/5]">
      <!-- col-[2-5] doesn't work -->
      <img src="https://image.scoopwhoop.com/w620/s3.scoopwhoop.com/anj/jf/946880113_3.jpg.webp" data-src="https://s3.scoopwhoop.com/anj/jf/946880113_3.jpg" alt="" class="load" />
      <figcaption>Source: <a href="http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2jjkww" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">dailymotion.com</a></figcaption>
    </figure>

    <h2>2. Hard To Be A God (2013)</h2>
    <p class="sw-para">Based on the&nbsp;Arkady and Boris Strugatsky novel of the same name, <i>Hard To Be A God</i>&nbsp;is a Russian sci-fi film set in a retroesque dystopic alien planet where intellectual thought is outlawed and humans are basically still stuck in a world similar to the dark ages. This one's as brutal as it is dark and uneasy to watch.</p>
    <figure class="sw-media">
      <img src="https://image.scoopwhoop.com/w620/s3.scoopwhoop.com/anj/jf/64386347_3.jpg.webp" data-src="https://s3.scoopwhoop.com/anj/jf/64386347_3.jpg" alt="" class="load" />
      <figcaption>Source: <a href="http://www.telegraph.co.uk/film/hard-to-be-a-god/review/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">telegraph.co.uk</a></figcaption>
    </figure>

    <h2>3. Fear And Loathing In Las Vegas (1998)</h2>
    <p class="sw-para">An easy pick; and, for those who haven't watched it, <i>Fear And Loathing</i>&nbsp;is a must on your epic mindfuck list. Starring Johnny Depp and&nbsp;Benicio del Toro in a hazed out and psychotropic drug infused journey through Las Vegas, this film is a tripped out experience.</p>
    <figure class="sw-media">
      <img src="https://image.scoopwhoop.com/w620/s3.scoopwhoop.com/anj/jf/126406619_3.jpg.webp" data-src="https://s3.scoopwhoop.com/anj/jf/126406619_3.jpg" alt="" class="load" />
      <figcaption>Source: <a href="http://www.silverlakepictureshow.com/show/fear-and-loathing-in-las-vegas/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">silverlakepictureshow.com</a></figcaption>
    </figure>

    <h2>4. El Topo (1970)</h2>
    <p class="sw-para">Directed by&nbsp;Alejandro Jodorowsky, <i>El Topo</i>&nbsp;is an American-Western following the story of a violent gun slinger in the west on a journey to find enlightenment. <i>El Topo </i>is a fairly graphic and almost caricature like movie with an indirect plot and extremely twisted character play.&nbsp;</p>
    <figure class="sw-media">
      <img src="https://image.scoopwhoop.com/w620/s4.scoopwhoop.com/anj/jf/293987293_3.jpg.webp" data-src="https://s4.scoopwhoop.com/anj/jf/293987293_3.jpg" alt="" class="load" />
      <figcaption>Source: <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Uqb4Jy0GTg" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">youtube.com</a></figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

It has 5 grid columns mentioned by `grid-cols-[1fr,70px,min(70ch,calc(100%-64px)),70px,1fr]`

I want my layout to be centered, i.e, staying within `min(70ch,calc(100%-64px))` with only images staying outside , i.e, `70px,min(70ch,calc(100%-64px)),70px`

Everything is in `3/4` column.

I want my images to be in `2/5` but it doesn't work because it is not a direct child. It's a grandchild.

The reason I need to do this is I want to use `@tailwindcss/typography` which needs `prose` class to be added to the top, hence, the additional `div`. If I put the `prose` class on the parent `div` then my `h1` styles would change which I don't want.

I also can't remove the `div` which has class `prose` as the post gets dynamically inserted using `mdx`. This is just an example but my real blog project contains code like this:

```
<div className="wrapper grid grid-cols-[1fr,70px,min(70ch,calc(100%-64px)),70px,1fr] gap-8 mb-24">
    <div className="mt-24 col-[3/4]">
        <dl>
            <dt className="sr-only">Published on</dt>
            <dd className="mb-2 font-medium text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
                <time dateTime={meta.date.toLocaleString()}>{formatDate(meta.date.toString())}</time>
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <ShiftBy x={-2}>
            <h1 className="text-5xl font-alegreya">{meta.title}</h1>
        </ShiftBy>
        <h2 className="text-xl font-medium text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
            {meta.description}
        </h2>
    </div>
    <div className="prose dark:prose-light col-[2/5]">
        <Component components={MDXComponents} />
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make the `figure` use `2/5` column? Ideally, I would love to have a solution in CSS Grid knowing my constraints, otherwise, if it's not possible `flex` will do or any other hacks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's a grandchild, it's not really going to be possible. What I would recommend is splitting your post into two grids. The first one being for the main display, and the second one being for the body of the article.

There are certainly some odd ways of going about it here, but I believe this is what you're going for: https://play.tailwindcss.com/gfnljMCxJN?layout=horizontal

```html
<div class="wrapper grid grid-cols-[1fr,70px,min(70ch,calc(100%-64px)),70px,1fr] gap-8 mb-24">
  <div class="mt-24 col-[3/4]">
    <dl>
      <dt class="sr-only">Published on</dt>
      <dd class="mb-2 font-medium text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
        <time datetime="2021-07-14T11:46:03.123Z">July 14, 2021</time>
      </dd>
    </dl>
    <ShiftBy x="{-2}">
      <h1 class="text-5xl font-alegreya">20 More Mindfuck Movies For The Brain Scrambling Experience</h1>
    </ShiftBy>
  </div>
  <div class="prose dark:prose-light max-w-full wrapper col-[2/5] grid grid-cols-[70px,1fr,70px] gap-8 mb-24">
    <p class="sw-para col-start-2">The predecessor to this list of mindfuck feature films showcased the average mind-numbing and quasi-discomposing stories from some great film makers. While you relished <a href="http://www.scoopwhoop.com/entertainment/20-mindfuck-hollywood-movies/" target="_blank">the previous list</a>, we felt we should explore different aspects and shades of an epic mindfuck. From the uneasy viewing to the unsettling, the 'what did I just watch' to the 'why did I just watch this', here's a renewed thought-blender list we compiled for you.</p>
    <h2 class="col-start-2">1. Neco Z Alenky/Alice (1988)&nbsp;</h2>
    <p class="sw-para col-start-2">A surreal and almost grimy adaptation of <i>Alice In Wonderland, </i>Czech&nbsp;director Jan Svankmajer managed to come up with a low budget film with a unique perspective on retelling the story and far from elaborate filming devices like stop motion and dark lighting. <i>Alice</i>&nbsp;is a complete trip.</p>
    <figure class="sw-media col-span-3">
      <!-- col-[2-5] doesn't work -->
      <img class="w-full" src="https://image.scoopwhoop.com/w620/s3.scoopwhoop.com/anj/jf/946880113_3.jpg.webp" data-src="https://s3.scoopwhoop.com/anj/jf/946880113_3.jpg" alt="" class="load" />
      <figcaption>Source: <a href="http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2jjkww" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">dailymotion.com</a></figcaption>
    </figure>
    <h2 class="col-start-2">2. Hard To Be A God (2013)</h2>
    <p class="sw-para col-start-2">Based on the&nbsp;Arkady and Boris Strugatsky novel of the same name, <i>Hard To Be A God</i>&nbsp;is a Russian sci-fi film set in a retroesque dystopic alien planet where intellectual thought is outlawed and humans are basically still stuck in a world similar to the dark ages. This one's as brutal as it is dark and uneasy to watch.</p>
    <figure class="sw-media col-span-3">
      <img class="w-full" src="https://image.scoopwhoop.com/w620/s3.scoopwhoop.com/anj/jf/64386347_3.jpg.webp" data-src="https://s3.scoopwhoop.com/anj/jf/64386347_3.jpg" alt="" class="load" />
      <figcaption>Source: <a href="http://www.telegraph.co.uk/film/hard-to-be-a-god/review/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">telegraph.co.uk</a></figcaption>
    </figure>
    <h2 class="col-start-2">3. Fear And Loathing In Las Vegas (1998)</h2>
    <p class="sw-para col-start-2">An easy pick; and, for those who haven't watched it, <i>Fear And Loathing</i>&nbsp;is a must on your epic mindfuck list. Starring Johnny Depp and&nbsp;Benicio del Toro in a hazed out and psychotropic drug infused journey through Las Vegas, this film is a tripped out experience.</p>
    <figure class="sw-media col-span-3">
      <img class="w-full" src="https://image.scoopwhoop.com/w620/s3.scoopwhoop.com/anj/jf/126406619_3.jpg.webp" data-src="https://s3.scoopwhoop.com/anj/jf/126406619_3.jpg" alt="" class="load" />
      <figcaption>Source: <a href="http://www.silverlakepictureshow.com/show/fear-and-loathing-in-las-vegas/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">silverlakepictureshow.com</a></figcaption>
    </figure>
    <h2 class="col-start-2">4. El Topo (1970)</h2>
    <p class="sw-para col-start-2">Directed by&nbsp;Alejandro Jodorowsky, <i>El Topo</i>&nbsp;is an American-Western following the story of a violent gun slinger in the west on a journey to find enlightenment. <i>El Topo </i>is a fairly graphic and almost caricature like movie with an indirect plot and extremely twisted character play.&nbsp;</p>
    <figure class="sw-media col-span-3">
      <img class="w-full" src="https://image.scoopwhoop.com/w620/s4.scoopwhoop.com/anj/jf/293987293_3.jpg.webp" data-src="https://s4.scoopwhoop.com/anj/jf/293987293_3.jpg" alt="" class="load" />
      <figcaption>Source: <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Uqb4Jy0GTg" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">youtube.com</a></figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically, I made the body of the article be a grid from the first 70px gutter to the other `col-[2/5]` and then gave it its own grid `grid grid-cols-[70px,1fr,70px]`. The part where it got tricky is that you are wrapping it in prose, which is good, but it has a max width set, so I needed to override that with `max-w-full`. From there, you're just setting the columns you want the contest of the article to go. All text should be `col-start-2` and figures should be `col-span-3`. After that, you need your figure images to be 100%, so add `w-full`.

There you go, Tailwind grid with images breakout of the copy.

Comment: Hey David, that's exactly how it's supposed to look. Thank you. I have a question though. Can I set `col-start-2` by default somewhere & `col-span-3` for just images because as you can see the content comes in dynamically through `<Component components={MDXComponents} />`? If not, I'd probably have to manually replace every element using `MDXComponents` I imagine, which is not that hard but still too much work for a simple thing.

Comment: You can write a small bit of CSS that would cover it. So let it come in from the component and have the layout/grid set up by tailwind, but use some `@apply` or plain styling in CSS to do the same thing.

Comment: Happy to help! `.wrapper * { grid-column: 2; } .wrapper figure { grid-column: 1 / -1; } .wrapper figure img { width: 100%; }`

Comment: Hey David, I'm wondering does this break the full-bleed layout fully as mentioned on https://www.joshwcomeau.com/css/full-bleed/

Comment: @deadcoder0904 this should in theory be the same thing. Because you’re doing tailwind, and wrapping everything a step higher it requires the extra step. Also, you need to do some work to have it work responsively, but the principle is the same. You’re just setting the grid for the content part and having the full bleed there.